# Dynamic int pointer address?

Tags: c++

I have been confused about displaying the address of a dynamic integer.
When I output ptr and &ptr I receive two different addresses, however I am unsure about which address is correctly pointing to the value of the pointer.

```
int main()
{

//Setting pointer to null.
int *ptr = NULL;

ptr = new int;

*ptr = 10;

//Displaying value the pointer is pointing to, and the address.
cout << "Value pointing to : " << *ptr << endl;
cout << "Address : " << ptr << endl;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement

```
ptr = new int;
```

allocates integer in memory and stores the address of the integer in the pointer variable ptr.

ptr itself is a variable and will have an address associated with it.
So ptr is a variable which stores address of another variable.
When you do

```
cout << ptr;
```

you are printing the address of the variable ptr is pointing to.

In contrast

```
cout << &ptr;
```

will print the address of ptr itself not that of the variable it is pointing to.